# How to create and return an anonymous JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

Imagine that I want to return an object like this

```
{name : "A", age : 23}
```

How we can done it actually, there is much way in stackoverflow but the json data always return from API. I Just want to return that simple object

Comment: How is this even related to JSON?

Comment: C# is not javascript. not even close, its an strongly typed language. Also return an object from what? you need to add code, otherwise we have no context (or domain) in what you are trying to do. Please edit this question with more information

Comment: Show us your API endpoint what are you returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using anonymous type in c#

```
new {name="A",age="23"}
```

This allows you to create an object on demand without creating a concrete class

Comment: i want to retun inside function of the controller in.net core

Comment: your code make it error actually

Comment: it will work. you might have taken my old answer which i had accidentally included `object` keywork

Comment: even though he use `object` it should work. I guess OP is trying to return anonymous object and return type of action method is different(it is just a guess) It would be really great if @argawirawan, give us more context on what error he/she is facing